# This is a test run to see what its like to post to stack overflow

Tags: arduino-ide

Hey I am new to coding and just wanted to try a test post in the forum. I am uploading code feel free to look it over and comment any suggestions or recommendation to the format or posting style of my question

```
//Brandon Markham
//Prime Integer Algorithm
//05/16/20

int userNum;
int origNum;
int count;
char userChoice;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Please enter an integer greater than 2 to see if it is prime.");
  Serial.println("If the entered number is not prime, the program will display ");
  Serial.println("the closest prime integer less than the number entered.\n");
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {
  }

  userNum = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.print("Number entered was: ");
  Serial.println(userNum);

  while (userNum <= 2) {
    Serial.println("Please enter a valid input greater than 2.\n");

    while (Serial.available() == 0) {
    }
    userNum = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.print("The number entered was: ");
    Serial.println(userNum);
  }

  origNum = userNum;
  PrimeInteger(userNum, origNum, count);

  Serial.print("Would you like to test another integer?\n");
  Serial.print("Select Y for yes and N for no.\n\n");

  while (Serial.available() == 0) {
  }
  userChoice = Serial.read();
  Serial.print("User choice was: ");
  Serial.println(userChoice);

  while (userChoice != 'y' && userChoice != 'Y' && userChoice != 'n' && userChoice != 'N') {
    Serial.println("Please enter valid input Y/y or N/n.\n");

    while (Serial.available() == 0) {
    }
    userChoice = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("User choice was: ");
    Serial.println(userChoice);
  }

  while (userChoice == 'Y' || userChoice == 'y') {
    Serial.println("Please enter another integer greater than 2.\n");
    break;
  }

  while (userChoice == 'N' || userChoice == 'n') {
    Serial.println("This program has terminated successuflly.");
    delay(1000);
    exit(0);
  }
}

void PrimeInteger(int uNum, int oNum, int c) {

  bool isPrimeInteger = true;

  if (uNum <= 1) {
    isPrimeInteger = false;
  }

  for (int i = 2; i <= uNum / 2; ++i) {
    if (uNum % i == 0) {
      isPrimeInteger = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (isPrimeInteger && c > 0) {
    Serial.print(uNum);
    Serial.print(" is the closest prime integer to ");
    Serial.print(oNum);
    Serial.println(".");
    Serial.println();
    return;
  }

  else if (isPrimeInteger) {
    Serial.print(uNum);
    Serial.print(" is a prime number\n");
    Serial.println();
    return;
  }

  if (!isPrimeInteger) {
    c++;
    uNum = uNum - 1;
    PrimeInteger(uNum, oNum, c);
  }
}
```

This program takes a number and determines if it is prime. If the number is not prime the program decrements the number to the nearest available prime number less than the number entered.

The program was written in the Arduino IDE

Comment: Welcome. You haven't included a question or problem you want to solve, so this question will  probably be closed because it's not really a question. Stack Overflow uses a clear question-and-answer format: you ask a specific question and get a specific answer. There are some other sites on the Stack Exchange network like https://codereview.stackexchange.com where "please review my code and tell me any way to improve it" is on-topic.